# Why SpriteKit References Not Showing SVG Files?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

Recently we replaced all of our raster images in our Xcode Project with Scalable Vector Graphics (SVG). After doing this we noticed that Xcode does not allow us to see the image in the SpriteKit Scene File (.sks). Does anyone know how this can be fixed so that we can properly design our levels?

Thank you.

[image: This is how the SKReferences look like in the Sprite Level Editor]

[image: This is what the Sprite looks like when in the reference file]

Comment: Same problem here. I guess no solution/fix for this?